# Why can't I disable MTU discovery on Windows socket? IP_PMTUDISC_DONT fails to set

Tags: c, windows, sockets, udp

I'm trying to build uftp on Windows.  It's a UDP transfer client/server.

I was eventually able to make static binaries with OpenSSL linked in. However I'm still having a problem with one bit of code. It fails to set the IP_PMTUDISC_DONT flag on the socket.

When I run the code Windows errors:

```
> uftpd.exe -D C:\xfertest\ -p 1044 -d -T c:\tmp

Error disabling MTU discovery: (10042) An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call.
Error leaving multicast group: (10038) An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

This is the code that is trying to set the flag on the socket in client_init.c:

```
#ifdef IP_MTU_DISCOVER
{
    int mtuflag = IP_PMTUDISC_DONT;
    if (setsockopt(listener, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &mtuflag, sizeof(mtuflag)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        sockerror(0, 0, 0, "Error disabling MTU discovery");
        closesocket(listener);
        exit(ERR_SOCKET);
    }
}
#endif
```

This is built on Windows Server 2016 with VS2017 community edition.

I have tried testing builds that don't include this flag, but they seem to have far worse performance (tons of NAKs), which maybe isn't a surprise if this causes fragmentation.

Can anyone think of why I can't setsockopt() on this? The listener is indeed a socket as created in the same file by `listener = socket(family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`. I see other feedback on the internet claiming that some of these APIs may have changed through time. I will see if I can build on earlier VS and OS versions, but I am hoping someone who has hit this before can point out a clear path to a solution faster than I can.

Comment: How do you get your `listener` socket?  How do you know the value held in `listener` is correct?  With the lack of context, no one is going to be able to anything other than guess.  [You need to post an MCVE.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to strip it out to an MCVE.  I was hoping that showing the listener creation would suffice.  Every other call on this socket works, so it's odd that it could be anything other than a socket.  But I don't really know the Windows Socket APIs so your point is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Support for `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` simply didn't exist yet in Windows Server 2016.

`IP_MTU_DISCOVER` was implemented in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) for UDP sockets in Windows 10 build 15002 (see WSL issues [#69](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/69), [#170](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/170), [#717](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/717), and [#720](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/720) on GitHub):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-15002

> Implemented IP_MTU_DISCOVER INET socket option (GH #720, 717, 170, 69)

`IP_MTU_DISCOVER` was implemented in WSL for TCP sockets in Windows 10 build 16215 (see WSL issues [#1639](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1639), [#2115](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2115), and [#2205](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2205) on GitHub):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-16215

> Added support for IP_MTU_DISCOVER for TCP sockets. [GH 1639, 2115, 2205]

Just because the **preprocessor** has `#define`'d a value for `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` doesn't guarantee the **target OS** that your code ends up running on actually supports `IP_MTU_DISCOVER`.  You need to run the code and ignore the `WSAENOPROTOOPT` error from `setsockopt()` if it occurs, eg:

```
#ifdef IP_MTU_DISCOVER
{
    int mtuflag = IP_PMTUDISC_DONT;
    if (setsockopt(listener, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &mtuflag, sizeof(mtuflag)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAENOPROTOOPT) {
            sockerror(0, 0, 0, "Error disabling MTU discovery");
            closesocket(listener);
            exit(ERR_SOCKET);
        }
        // IP_MTU_DISCOVER is NOT supported on this OS!
        // Do something else, or just move on...
    }
}
#endif
```